# Haskell Warp/Wai and HTTPS -- how to make them work?

Tags: haskell, ssl, https, haskell-warp

I have a basic hello-world application in Haskell Servant and Warp. This is not real code but for the sake of simplicity let's say I'm using it:

```
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Servant


personAPI :: Proxy PersonAPI
personAPI = Proxy

server :: Server PersonAPI
server = return people

app :: Application
app = serve personAPI server

serveApp :: IO ()
serveApp = run 80 app
```

It works fine on a server. With http.

I'm not using nginx or apache, I run it as-is and at this point it's fine for me.

But with https it won't load the page. I've installed https certificate but I gathered that I should somehow setup warp/wai to use it, because by default it won't use it. There's shortage of information about this - warp/wai and SSL, I haven't found anything. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is using the [warp-tls](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-tls) library - settup your certificate files in the `TLSSettings` (I would try [`tlsSettings`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-tls-3.2.0/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-WarpTLS.html#v:tlsSettings) first) and use [`runTLS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-tls-3.2.0/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-WarpTLS.html#v:runTLS) instead of `run`:

```
serveApp :: IO ()
serveApp = do
   let tls = tlsSettings "pathToCert" "pathToKey"
   runTLS tls (setPort 443 defaultSettings) app
```

Comment: you know everything!

Comment: but at warp-tls it says "Support for SSL is now obsoleted. " and SSL is what I need.

Comment: I can assure you I know very little (beside how to enter queries into Hayoo ;))

Comment: I've never heard of Hayoo before, that's not me.

Comment: well maybe they moved it somewhere else but it should still work

Comment: it's like Hoogle but searches more packages by default

Comment: I looked around a bit and I think the comment in the package is a bit misleading: http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2015/07/http2 (if I get it correctly it means that current browsers will establish TLS over the headers so you probably don't need the open 443 port anymore and can use 80(?) - as I said: I am no expert on this)